# G drive api delete files in a folder in my drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have multiple users on chromeboxes downloading customers' files to their local machines. Those files need to be deleted at the end of each day.
I wrote a script to delete files from a folder in team drive but it turned out that folders in team drives cannot be shared(and they don't appear in Chrome downloads settings). 
So with my next step I created a folder in my drive and shared it with everyone. This appears in their downloads settings but the script I wrote requires a team drive id, which obviously I cannot get for my drive.
How can I tackle this problem? Any idea where I can find my drive's ID? Or how else how can I access files in my drive only?

Comment: Why would you write a script for team drive when you're working on your personal drive? And, where's the script?

Comment: Ok, it turned out that I'm quite limited in what I can do with this. Basically I wanted to use team drives initially but my users couldn't set them as their default folder. I can't get this to run anyway because my script can't delete files uploaded by users. I confirmed with Google there's no solution to this problem. Thanks anyway.